# Tensorboard shows the same result after specifying a new logdir in jupyter notebook

Tags: deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, tensorboard

I used the following lines to open a tensorboard for one log directory in a Jupyter notebook:

```
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir saved_models/tutorial5/GoogleNetLocal/lightning_logs/version_2/
```

In another cell, I wanted to open another board for a different directory using `%tensorboard --logdir ./saved_models/tutorial5/ResNetLocal/lightning_logs/version_0/`. However, it still shows the previous board as shown below. Why it doesn't create a new board for the second directory?

Thank you so much for your help!

[image: Same board as before]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll share the answer to this question in case it might be useful for someone else:

The issue can be solved by specifying a different port using `--port xxxx` when running `%tensorboard`